# How to select sequenc data

Tags: pandas, sequence

I dont know how can I start with filttering the data were are 3 and more sequenc data.For example my basic data are numbers under the column **stevilo** (188774,18775,18814) or even more than 3 (maybe is posibility to change the sequece number (more than 3, more than 2 or exactly number 3)).

```
    stevilo             cas F   
1   Pattern number : 1  B3341 
2   Pattern number : 2  B3342
7   18774               18.11.2019 11:07 
8   18775               18.11.2019 11:09 
8   18776               18.11.2019 11:20 
26  Pattern number : 1  B2633-CELA 
56  18814               18.11.2019 12:44 
57  18815               18.11.2019 12:45 
63  Pattern number : 1  B3343 
70  18819               18.11.2019 12:52 
76  Pattern number : 1  B1822A
327 19022               18.11.2019 19:21
328 19023               18.11.2019 19:23
329 19024               18.11.2019 19:25
330 19025               18.11.2019 19:26
331 19026               18.11.2019 19:27
332 19027               18.11.2019 19:28
333 19028               18.11.2019 19:30
334 19029               18.11.2019 19:31
335 19030               18.11.2019 19:32
345 19040               18.11.2019 19:46
346 19041               18.11.2019 19:48
349 19044               18.11.2019 20:21
```

I want to copy the data when are 3 sequence data for example (19022, 19023, 19024) and my out put data will be like :

```
1   Pattern number : 1  B3341 
2   Pattern number : 2  B3342
7   18774               18.11.2019 11:07 
8   18775               18.11.2019 11:09 
8   18776               18.11.2019 11:20 
76  Pattern number : 1  B1822A
327 19022               18.11.2019 19:21
328 19023               18.11.2019 19:23
329 19024               18.11.2019 19:25
330 19025               18.11.2019 19:26
331 19026               18.11.2019 19:27
332 19027               18.11.2019 19:28
333 19028               18.11.2019 19:30
334 19029               18.11.2019 19:31
335 19030               18.11.2019 19:32
```

Comment: Do you truly need to verify there is a pattern by checking the difference between consecutive rows, or like in your example, is it enough to just assume everything below a row with `'Pattern number : XX'` belongs to the same "pattern"?

Comment: I need sequence datas like my out put up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we add an auxillary column `group` to indicate what group (starts with 'Pattern number ...' row) the row belongs to. Then we transform this column based on the numbers in the `stevilo` column into a `True`/`False` indicator using the `find_pattern` function:

- groups with just the header and no numbers (length of 1) are included
- groups with less than 4 rows (including header row) are excluded
- all remaining groups are (partially) included up to the first row where the numbers are non-consequtive

```
def find_pattern(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return True
    if len(x) < 4:
        return False
    x = pd.to_numeric(x, 'coerce')
    diff = x.values - x.shift().values
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
        end = np.argwhere(diff > 1)
    if len(end) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        end = end[0][0]
        diff[:end] = True
        diff[end:] = False
        return diff
```

Example for your sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

s = """    stevilo             cas F   
1   Pattern number : 1  B3341 
2   Pattern number : 2  B3342
7   18774               18.11.2019 11:07 
8   18775               18.11.2019 11:09 
8   18776               18.11.2019 11:20 
26  Pattern number : 1  B2633-CELA 
56  18814               18.11.2019 12:44 
57  18815               18.11.2019 12:45 
63  Pattern number : 1  B3343 
70  18819               18.11.2019 12:52 
76  Pattern number : 1  B1822A
327 19022               18.11.2019 19:21
328 19023               18.11.2019 19:23
329 19024               18.11.2019 19:25
330 19025               18.11.2019 19:26
331 19026               18.11.2019 19:27
332 19027               18.11.2019 19:28
333 19028               18.11.2019 19:30
334 19029               18.11.2019 19:31
335 19030               18.11.2019 19:32
345 19040               18.11.2019 19:46
346 19041               18.11.2019 19:48
349 19044               18.11.2019 20:21"""

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(s), [(0,3),(4,23),(24,222)]).set_index('Unnamed: 0')
del df.index.name

df['group'] = np.where(df.stevilo.str.startswith('Pattern'), df.index, np.nan)
df.group = df.group.ffill()

df.group = df.groupby('group').stevilo.transform(find_pattern).astype(bool)
res = df[df.group].drop('group',1)
```

Outpuf of `print(res)`:

```
                stevilo             cas F
1    Pattern number : 1             B3341
2    Pattern number : 2             B3342
7                 18774  18.11.2019 11:07
8                 18775  18.11.2019 11:09
8                 18776  18.11.2019 11:20
76   Pattern number : 1            B1822A
327               19022  18.11.2019 19:21
328               19023  18.11.2019 19:23
329               19024  18.11.2019 19:25
330               19025  18.11.2019 19:26
331               19026  18.11.2019 19:27
332               19027  18.11.2019 19:28
333               19028  18.11.2019 19:30
334               19029  18.11.2019 19:31
335               19030  18.11.2019 19:32
```

(if multiple group header rows should have the same index value you'll have to reset the index to a range index and use this new index for the group values)

Comment: Thank you very much. It s very helpfull. But I have another error:  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (436,) (5135,) ().

Comment: in the example data or in your real data? At what line of code?

Comment: In my real data, I will try again.    
----> 4 g['group'] = np.where(g.stevilo.str.startswith('Pattern'), df.index, np.nan)

Comment: Its working! Thank you again, I made mistake (wrong datafram name).